# swift get range of attribute by index in NSAttributedString

Tags: swift, textview, nsattributedstring

I have a NSAttributedString with 2 attributes

From 0 to 5 {0,5} -> attribute1

from 6 to 10 {6,10} -> attribute2

I use

```
let attributes = textView.textStorage.attributes(at: 7, longestEffectiveRange: nil, in: NSRange(location: 0, length: textView.textStorage.length))
```

to get attribute at index 7.

Is possibile have the full range of attribute at index 7?

In my example I should get 6-10

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using `longestEffectiveRange`?

Comment: Yes, but it only returns the value of the attribute, not the full range of the attribute itself

Comment: Post a [mre] please.

Comment: What are "full range" and "the attribute", can you give an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, using `enumerateAttributes` provide by `NSAttributedString` to do that. Means that take all the range of each attribute in your string and find which range contains your index

Code will be like this

```swift
var index = 7

attributeString.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(location: 0, length: attributeString.length), using: {
    _, range, _ in
    // if index in range
    if range.contains(index) {
        print("range: ", range)
        // do your code here
    }
})
```